# XSD FOR XML element multiple occurrences

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

i'm new to xsd and i want to generate xml like below with `STUDENTRECORD` occurring multiple times. i'm using jaxb to generate classes on the xsd

```
<STUDENTDETAIL>
  <STUDENTINFORMATION>
    <STUDENTRECORD>
        <NAME>ABC</NAME>
        <CLASS>4</CLASS>
        <MAJOR>SCIENCE</MAJOR>
        <GRADE>A</GRADE>
    </STUDENTRECORD>
    <STUDENTRECORD>
        <NAME>DEF</NAME>
        <CLASS>4</CLASS>
        <MAJOR>SCIENCE</MAJOR>
        <GRADE>B</GRADE>
    </STUDENTRECORD>
</STUDENTINFORMATION>
```

My current xsd which generates STUDENTRECORD only once.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://webservice.com/WS" targetNamespace="http://webservice.com/WS" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
<xs:element name="Student" type="Student"/>
<xs:complexType name="Student">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="STUDENTDETAIL">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="STUDENTINFORMATION">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="STUDENTRECORD">
                                    <xs:complexType>
                                        <xs:sequence>
                                            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="NAME"/>
                                            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="CLASS"/>
                                            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="MAJOR"/>
                                            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="GRADE"/>
                                        </xs:sequence>
                                    </xs:complexType>
                                </xs:element>
                            </xs:sequence>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Please help to fix.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set a `maxOccurs` attribute on the *STUDENTRECORD* element declaration, like this:

```
<xs:element name="STUDENTRECORD" maxOccurs="unbounded">
```

This will allow the `<STUDENTRECORD>` to appear as many times you want. By default a given element is required to appear once.

Similarly, you can set `minOccurs` attribute to specify the minimal number of occurrences of an element.